# Background colour not filling div

Tags: html, css

For an example I want my wrapper div to have a red background color and it will fill down as other divs are placed inside it.

However since it is centered using margin: auto; and the divs inside it are floated left the colour does not continue down. If i remove the margin auto and replace it with float:left; then the colour will continue as it should.

I have got around this by keeping my margin auto and using overflow: hidden which allows the colour to flow down. However for this site i am working on I need to keep the overflow visible.

Is there another way I can get this to work? Also if you know, could you explain why overflow hidden works in the way it does.

Thank you

Comment: *Really* hard to debug these issues without any code as an example to look at. Often they are rather unique situations as people tend to take many different approaches to css and html. Could you copy some of your non sensitive html and css into ***[`http://jsfiddle.net`](http://jsfiddle.net)***, click "Save", and then post the link here so we can see what is going on?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/USvkA/ from the code you can see the red background colour. if you remove float left from the wrapper and replace it with margin auto you can see the red disappearing.

Comment: That is indeed an interesting situation. The issue is that without `float` the wrapper actually has a height of `0px`. I am not sure what causes `float` to give the `.wrapper` div height. Hopefully someone else can shed some light on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workaround is to put a div inside that div...

Like this...

```
<div id="container"> 

   <div id="colordiv">

   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Where container is an auto margined 'container', and the color div is 100% color fill for that container.

This way you can make the main container any width, the rest will follow, and the color continues as far as the content

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/yp9GD/3/)

[ANOTHER DEMO - smaller divs](http://jsfiddle.net/yp9GD/4/)

As for your overflow question....Im not sure at all why thats the case

Comment: jsfiddle.net/USvkA from the code you can see the red background colour. if you remove float left from the wrapper and replace it with margin auto you can see the red disappearing.

Comment: I know that an extra div would work but that is what i am trying to avoid

Answer (score 0):

`display: flex` will allow the background to fill in the same way as the ellusive `overflow: hidden` does.

You then have to contend with:

- Margins not collapsing - if that's important to you
- Setting alignment, which if you have an existing layout may be trivial or complex

Note: One disadvantage of `overflow: hidden` is it breaks sticky positioning.