# Creating a fixed width element and a responsive element together

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have a page which has a max-width of 1200px.

The left section is `840px` or `70%` Within this there are going to be articles which has details on the left `40px` which I want to keep fixed and the rest `800px` responsive.

The article is `100%` wide `(840px max)`, the element which has class named `homeArtDets` is `40px` and the element which has class named `homeArt` is `95.23809523809524% (800px max, 800/840 * 100)` suppose to be responsive.

**here is the html structure**

```
<article>
    <div class="homeArtDets">
        <div class="homeArtCat">BLG</div>
        <div class="homeArtDate">05<br>Jun<br>2013</div>
    </div>
    <div class="homeArt">
        <div class="homeArtText">
            <h2>New Adventures Conference</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis, dolorem, obcaecati sint odit ad sit provident nesciunt nobis eaque vel saepe harum in cumque fugit fuga quas accusamus illo est hic necessitatibus rerum debitis ipsum mollitia error possimus. Atque, asperiores quibusdam nemo nesciunt! Nesciunt, amet numquam impedit sit cum vitae.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="homeArtImg"><img src="images/newadventures.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="homeArtInfo"><p>Posted on 5th June 2013 by Pierce McGeough</p></div>
    </div>
</article>
```

take a look on this below fiddle

I have it on jsFiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/59J5D/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/59J5D/1/

```css
.homeArtDets {
    float: left;
    width: 40px;
}
.homeArt {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Yes thats it. So my mistake was giving the .homeArt a width and floating it?

Comment: It wasn't a mistake as such. I've [used a simple solution](http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/#making-room-for-floats) to your problem.

Comment: Yes I use it too for wrappers with a background colour that doesnt automatically fill out once populated with other elements and divs. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17055372/background-colour-not-filling-div